# Checking if a file is empty in unix

Tags: shell, unix

I'm trying to do something like

```
for i in {1..999}
do
#some commands here
        if [ ! -s text${i}.txt ]
        then
                break
        fi
done
```

But the file `text${i}` is not empty and this loop keeps exiting after going through it once but it should keep going and when I do

```
    for i in {1..999}
    do
    #some commands here
            if [ -s text${i}.txt ]
            then
                    break
            fi
    done
```

The program just runs forever.

Answer (score 4):

`-s` is for testing whether or not a file is empty, not `-f`. See [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_01.html) for some documentation.